# Views not rendered after transition event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm currently trying to build an app using backbone, require.js & jqm. I'm new to jquery mobile an I'm having strange rendering issues and I'm not able to track them down or fix them. So my question remains on a rather nebulous and phenomenal level - hopefully someone can help me out here. I've the feeling that I understood something wrong here.

So here's what I do:
Basically I'm using the router facilities of backbone.js and disabling all routing capabilities of jqm. Using (in main.js):

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```

After that I use the routing technique proposed by [Christophe Coenraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/) on his blog. Which basically looks like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

// Router constructor
initialize: function(){
  this.loginView = new LoginView(this);
  this.registerView = new RegisterView(this);
  this.user = new User(this);

  // Tell Backbone to listen for hashchange events
  Backbone.history.start();
},    

// Define routes
routes: {
  '': 'home',
  'login' : 'login',
  'registration' : 'registration',
},

/// Define route actions ///
// Home route
home: function() {
   this.user.isUserLoggedIn();
},
// Login route
login: function() {
  console.log("Welcome to the router - login route.");
  this.changePage(this.loginView);
},

registration:function() {
  console.log("Welcome to the router - registration route.");
  this.changePage(this.registerView);
},

changePage:function (page) {
    $("body").empty();

    $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');

    $("body").append($(page.el));

    page.render();
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", $(page.el), {transition: "pop", changeHash: false, reverse: false});

}});
```

Basically I've to views: The Login & RegisterView at the moment. When I naviagte to the RegisterView it works fine, but navigating backwards to login I can see the transition ("pop") - but after the transition the content is not shown in the browser. It is present in the DOM but I figures out that certain css classes are missing for example `"ui-page-active"` on the `data-role="page"`. When I apply that class manually I can see the LoginView but all events are lost (a click on the registration tab does not trigger anything).

I've the feeling that there is a conceptual misunderstanding on my side and I'm not able to figure out where the problem resides. I tried things like `.trigger("create")` but that looked rather like a helpless tryout than anything else.

I've set up a GitHub-Repository. I'm thankful for any help - thanks in advance and sorry for the confused question.

EDIT: Yeah... and here also the link to the [repo](https://github.com/nweis/myTour/).

Comment: It's nice that you set up a Github repo, but could you post the link? :)

Comment: Try `$('body').enhanceWithin();`.

Comment: @Omar: Thanks for your reply. I've added it after page.render() and tried it also after $(":mobile-pagecontainer"). Sadly no success on that.

Comment: Have you tried it this way `$("body").append($(page.el)).enhanceWithin();`?

Comment: @Omar: Thanks again for your reply. Yep - I've also checked that out. The result is, that also on the initial load all style attributes are not applied. Beside that the described effect above remains the same.

Comment: Try initializing JQM manually `$.mobile.initializePage();`

Comment: @Omar: Thanks again for your reply. Following effect: Loading symbol appears (page already rendered). Navigate to registration and back again. Login page disappears (like before) and reapears then. But no event listeners are working. But I'm not quite sure about the order it should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that I placed the configuration to prevent jqm in the wrong place. It has to reside in main.js before the actual app is loaded:

```
require(["jquery"], function( $ ){
    $( document ).one( "mobileinit", function() {
        //Set your configuration and event binding
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });


  require([
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app',

  ], function(App){

    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore don't pass a parameter to this function
    App.initialize();
  });

});
```

Thanks for the help anyways.